# Can't access to product's reviews in WooCommerce when using Gutenberg as editor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

I know that Gutenberg isn't supported on Woocommerce, but I'm trying it anyway and so far is quite good. Im doing it by:

```
function wplook_activate_gutenberg_products($can_edit, $post_type){
    if($post_type == 'product'){
        $can_edit = true;
    }
    return $can_edit;
}
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'wplook_activate_gutenberg_products', 10, 2);
```

What I notice that there is error when trying add some of the Woo blocks in products, so I decide to disable Woo blocks on products to avoid it. Works ok now.

But in backend and can't access to reviews. I see only comments section but this not working at all. Does anybody dealing with that somehow?

Comment: For those who found it because they want to enabe the Gutenberg editor for WooCommerce product without coding: https://wordpress.org/plugins/blocks-product-editor-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread trying to find a solution to your last part too.

When I have Gutenberg active on products, even with reviews enabled in WooCommerce settings, when I go to:

1. Product Data
2. Advanced
3. and try and toggle the "Enable Reviews" option

When I save and then refresh the change doesn't seem to take so I am unable to turn reviews on if they are currently off or turn them off if they are currently on.

I have tried to test all of the other options and checkboxes like virtual and downloadable and they all seem to save fine it just seems to be this one setting that doesn't get saved.

I am keeping note of everything I find on the matter and if I manage to find a solution I will come back to share. I'm not sure if it will help with your other issue though which I haven't faced.

Comment: I hope there are plans in Woo team for making Woo fully compatible with Gutenberg. I think there is an tricky way for creating Gutenberg product pages, with some hooks and ACF's fields. I will try it later, but I hope that Woo will be' Gutompatible' earlier.

Comment: I think the solution could be add another reviews by hook? Then just hide default reviews on WC product. Should work with Content Blocks with Blocksy Theme I think.